# XMLReader and HTML code in node?

Tags: php, xmlreader

I am using the XMLReader to go through my XML file. One of the nodes contains HTML code, but the reader seems to remove all the HTML code.

Code:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($file);
while($reader->read()) {
   $nodeName = $reader->name;
   if($nodeName == 'description') {
       $test = $reader->readString(); // HTML removed, why?
   }   
}
```

So, the description node contains `<b>this is a test</b>`, but the `$test` var only contains `this is a test` ... why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should put your html in a CDATA block!

Comment: the problem is, that a html tag is interpreted as xml tag (at least it tries). That's why there are no tags left after interpreting it. A CDATA block will prevent it from being interpreted. 

So if you can't change the generation, you will have to parse the file and replace the tags with something like **b** and interpret it later ....